# probabilistic regression in existing packages

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, software, probabilistic-programming

I know that typical machine-learning packages (such as scikit-learn or TensorFlow)
contain plenty of functions for probabilistic classification:
given a training set of pairs $(x_i,y_i)$, where $y_i$ is the label of the $i$th sample $x_i$,
and a test sample $x$, we can compute the probability distribution for its label $y$.
For example, in scikit-learn, this can be done using Neural Nets, Support Vector Machine, Decision Trees,
Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression, and probably many more methods.
But what about probabilistic regression, where the labels are real numbers,
and so the task can be stated as computing a cdf for the label of the test sample $x$?
I know scikit-learn has Gaussian Processes implemented, with various kernels.
Is it all?
Are there functions in common packages that produce non-Gaussian predictive distributions?

I understand that standard regression functions can be adapted to probabilistic regression:
for example, we can first fit a real-valued function $\mu(x)$ predicting the label $y$ given $x$
and then fit $\sigma^2(x)$ predicting $(y-\mu(x))^2$ given $x$.
This will give us a predictive distribution, $N(\mu(x),\sigma(x))$, for the label of $x$.
This could be adapted to non-Gaussian predictive distributions, but it looks awkward.
And in any case, I am looking for off-the-shelf solutions.

Comment: 1. I think you are assuming that the labels have to be real numbers in order to compute a CDF.  All you need is that the labels have an ordering, e.g, $A < B < C$ will do.  2. Logistic regression fits a non-Gaussian predictive distribution, to name just one.   Tree-based regression (GBM, RF, ...) and NN make no assumptions of Gaussianity.   It's not clear to me what your actual question is, since much of the first paragraph consists of functions that answer the question posed in the last sentence in the affirmative.

Comment: @jbowman: In the first part of my question I am talking about probabilistic classification, where there are only finitely many (say, 2, in the case of binary classification) possible labels.  There are lots of functions for this case.  In the second part I am talking about probabilistic regression, where the label space (=set of all possible labels) is the real line (or its sizeable, infinite and even uncountable, part, such as the interval $(0,\infty)$).  I am not really interested in the case of probabilistic classification with ordered labels.

Comment: Decision trees, Neural Nets, Gradient Boosting, Random Forests, and Support Vector Machines can, and are, all used for regression problems, and make no assumptions about Gaussianity.   Logistic regression obviously doesn't either, as it's trying to estimate probabilities.

Comment: @jbowman: Don't they output point predictions? How can you get probabilistic predictions (cdf's) from them in scikit-learn (or another popular package)?